# driver.findElement not working with safari but works fine with chrome and firefox

Tags: jasmine, protractor

So having a weird issue with the safari functionality.. it takes me couple of steps to reach this point but once i am here i am able to use code like:

```
await $$('.abc').count();
```

This returns the count but unfortunately code like this:

```
await driver.findElement(by.css('.add')).click();
```

It seems like that the element() or element.all() based functions are working fine on safari but driver.findElement() functions collapse. I did try several waits to make sure that the page loads before this is executed but all in vain. This piece of code works fine on safari and chrome.

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks! :)

Comment: Here is some more info:

Safari: 11.0.1
Node: 8.9.0
Protractor: 5.3.1

Comment: Can you provide stacktrace?

Comment: @xotabu4 , i have switched 2 iframes to reach this point but once i am in the iframe where this piece of code needs to run, it gives right count.. just does not click the button which means its in the iframe.